# How to reuse a rule as an action of another rule?

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

Eg:

> Rule1: Check if Person's Country is 'United States'
>
> Rule2: Check if Person's State is 'Washington, D.C.'
>
> Now Rule3  is combination of Rule1 and Rule2
>
> Rule3:         **if Rule1 then Rule2**
>
> here Rule2 is an action that will be executed if Rule1 is true

I know I can achieve this problem by writing **If Rule1 and Rule2 then execute Some Action Method**, but the main intention behind this question is: I want to execute another rule as an Action. How can I achieve it using CodeEffects?

Answer (score 0):

The use of a rule as rule action is not supported because this could lead to logical issues and hard-to-detect circular dependencies.

Use either Loop or Ruleset mode. Details can be found [here](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Editor-Modes)

Answer (score -1):

It should be noted that many other business rule products support the feature of inference and chaining of rules.  This is often implemented and talked about as [backward chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_chaining).

Comment: You could also link some examples of those products and point out if CodeEffects supports it or not.

Comment: The original question has nothing to do with rule chaining